# unable to create ckeditor instance in jquery ui dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, ckeditor, jquery-ui-dialog

```
$(function() {
        $('#dialog').dialog({
        dialogClass: 'edit-combo',
        width: 575,
        modal: true,
        open: function(event, ui) {
            $('#my-editor').ckeditor();
        }
    });

})
```

Here is my html

```
<textarea id="my-editor" name="my-editor" ></textarea>
```

Above script does not show any errors also.

Jquery ui dialog opens on load

Comment: Assuming that your html and css is valid, this should work as you expect it to (checked in firefox). Double-check the html, that the `<textarea>` is inside the `<div id=dialog>`; and make sure you include the correct paths to all jquery, jqueryui and ckeditor sources.

Comment: @blgt One thing I forget to mention is I am using angularjs